# Material UI popover fails to open on anchor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

I am trying to have a popover appear over an icon when hovering. I tried to adapt the code from here https://material-ui.com/components/popover/#mouse-over-interaction. My solution is below. I tried to remove some of the complexities of the project setup but had to include some extra stuff for clarity.

```
export interface Props {
  popoverAnchor?: HTMLElement;
  setPopoverAnchor: (anchor?: HTMLElement) => void;
}
```

render()

```
const {
  popoverAnchor,
  setPopoverAnchor
} = this.props;


const open = Boolean(popoverAnchor);

return(
```

...

```
  <div className={classes.flex}>
    <HelpOutlineIcon
      aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
      aria-haspopup="true"
      onMouseEnter={(event: any) => {
        setPopoverAnchor(event.currentTarget)
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => setPopoverAnchor()}
    />
    <Popover
      id="mouse-over-popover"
      className={(classes.popover)}
      classes={{
        paper: classes.paper,
      }}
      open={open}
      anchorEl={popoverAnchor}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'bottom',
        horizontal: 'left',
      }}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'left',
      }}
      onClose={() => setPopoverAnchor()}
      disableRestoreFocus
    >
      <Typography>I use Popover.</Typography>
    </Popover>
  </div>
```

constants.ts

```
export const SET_POPUP_ANCHOR = 'SET_POPUP_ANCHOR';
export type SET_POPUP_ANCHOR= typeof SET_POPUP_ANCHOR;
```

store.ts

```
export interface State {
  anchor?: HTMLElement;
}
```

actions.ts

```
export interface SetPopupAnchor {
  type: constants.SET_POPUP_ANCHOR;
  anchor?: HTMLElement;
}

export type Action = SetPopupAnchor;

export function handlePopoverAnchor(anchor?: HTMLElement): SetPopupAnchor {
  return {
    type: constants.SET_POPUP_ANCHOR,
    anchor: anchor
  }
}
```

DemoContainer.ts

```
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<actions.AnonymizationAction>) {
  return {
    setPopoverAnchor: (anchor?: HTMLElement) => dispatch(actions.handlePopoverAnchor(anchor))
  }
}
```

This fails to create any popup at all and no error appears on the console. after debugging i saw that the element object successfully makes it all the way to the the handlePopoverAnchor action meaning the state should have been changed.